# Alternative tag for center tag in html?

Tags: html, css

```html
 <center>
  <img src="/images/perform.png" width="40%" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</center>
```

Here i have used center tag..it shows image in center aligned but now i have to change center tag..is there any alternative tag for center tag?

Comment: what do you mean by "change center tag"? what is it that you expect your code to do?

Comment: Is CSS an option, instead of using a pre-defined tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one: `center` is deprecated in flavor of `css` solutions.
Actually, centering your example image is pretty easy

```
img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For additional reference: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 3):

Alternative? why you want to use a tag as `<center>` tag is depreciated because this can be done with small code of css.

You can just use `text-align:center` in parent, or `margin:0 auto` in child div.

**text-align:center**

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <img src="/images/perform.png" width="40%" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

**margin:0 auto**

```html
<div>
  <img src="/images/perform.png" width="40%" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" style="margin:0 auto; display:block;">
</div>
```

Comment: yes...text-align:center is not working but style="margin:0 auto; display:block;" this css working well

Comment: here `text-align:center` should also work perfectly unless if some other css code is not overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

The `center` tag in HTML has deprecated by **HTML 4** standard. That means it has been removed from web standards. However, it possible that most of browsers still support `center` tag. But it is not necessary for browsers to support `center` tag as it is not part of standard.

If you want center align an element, you should use `css` instead. You can use `text-align` property of `css` to change alignment of elements.

For example,

```css
#center-align {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="center-align">Some text</p>
```

In this example, I'm using `id` attribute to set alignment of paragraph. Instead of that, you may use any other css selector like class, tag name or any other indirect selectors.

References

1. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: Do not use the `id` attribute for that. Otherwise you are only allowed to have single centered element per page.